# How to store roe (fish eggs) at home in a refrigerator?

Tags: storage, bait

My boyfriend seems to think it’s OK to store his open container of roe on the top shelf of my refrigerator next to all of our food what do you think about this?

Comment: Charlie has a good answer about why it is not good for the fish eggs, I think you might be more concerned about potential health risks to yourself from the fish eggs can you clarify your focus?

Answer (score 3):

From what I have seen, you want to keep the eggs **away from oxygen to keep them good so you should probably put a lid on the container.**

> Unlike other baits that harden over time, salmon eggs get softer, making it more difficult to keep them on the hook. The solution? Vander Mause recommends storing the jar upside down. That way, the oil in the jar creates an airtight barrier behind the lid, keeping egg-ruining oxygen out.

[Why You Should Be Fishing With Salmon Roe Year-Round](https://www.fieldandstream.com/articles/fishing/2015/10/egg-%E2%80%99em-on-teach-this-old-bait-some-deadly-new-tricks)

You can also freeze them see,

- [From The Bait Lab: Egg Storage 101](http://www.pautzke.com/from-the-bait-lab-egg-storage-101/)
- [Learn Proper Long Term Egg Storage: No Freezer Burn! No Dehydration!](http://www.pautzke.com/learn-proper-long-term-egg-storage-no-freezer-burn-no-dehydration/)
- [Freezing Spawn Sacks](http://www.pautzke.com/freezing-spawn-sacks/)

Comment: You might want to add something about salmonella and such.